# Dynamically stream files into a zip file response

Tags: java, sockets, http, stream

I'm trying to dynamically zip my files as a response for the user, but for some reason they become slightly corrupted on the way. The client can receive them, open the zip folder and browse the files. However, opening or extracting them won't work.

Here's my code:

```
private void dynamicallyZipFiles(IHTTPSession session) {
    try {
        // Let's send the headers first
        OutputStream os = session.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8")), false);
        pw.append("HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n");
        printHeader(pw, "Connection", "keep-alive");
        printHeader(pw, "Content-Type", "application/zip, application/octet-stream");
        printHeader(pw, "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"pack.zip\"");
        printHeader(pw, "Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
        pw.append("\r\n");
        pw.flush();

        // Send all the files from the list of files
        ChunkedOutputStream cos = new ChunkedOutputStream(os);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(cos);
        final LinkedList<String> files = new LinkedList<String>();
        files.add("file1.txt");
        files.add("file2.txt");

        while (!files.isEmpty()) {
            String file = files.remove();
            File toBeSent = new File(file);
            try {
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(toBeSent);
                long BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
                byte[] buff = new byte[(int) BUFFER_SIZE];
                int len;
                while ((len = is.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buff, 0, len);
                }
                is.close();
                zos.flush();
                cos.flush();
                zos.closeEntry();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Files have been sent, send the closing chunk
        //cos.write("0\r\n\r\n".getBytes(), 0, "0\r\n\r\n".getBytes().length);
        // The above line of code was the problem! Without it, it works!

        cos.flush();
        zos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// Helper for printing headers
private void printHeader(PrintWriter pw, String key, String value) {
    pw.append(key).append(": ").append(value).append("\r\n");
}
```

I've been struggling for quite some hours already with this. I believe it has to have something to do with the closing chunk or with the closing of the connection?

I'm not sure what's the right order or way to close streams. I believe that when you have kind of "layered" streams and you close the top most one it will automatically close all the ones below too? And how about flush, if you flush a stream, will it flush the streams below it as well?
With this I mean that my ZipStream for example, if I close it, will it close all the other streams as well? And if I flush it, will it flush all the other streams as well again?

Comment: Should be so yes. Java -version says 8 to be more precise.

Comment: I do not know the libraries used, but I am puzzled about the `cos.write("0\r\n\r\n".getBytes(), 0, "0\r\n\r\n".getBytes().length);` line, why is it there? Should you not call cos.close() after flush instead?

Comment: Hi Stian! Yes, that line of code actually was what caused all the trouble!
By the definition of HTTP chunked transfer I thought that by writing that zero message to the end I would notify the browser I want to close the data transfer. But I was wrong. I'm not sure but apparently the .close() function does already something similar?
Please write your comment as an answer and I will be happy to accept it! Also if you could briefly explain what the close() actually does to a stream and the other streams children of the one being closed I'd be happy to hear.And how come I don't need to send the 0?